# How do I use circuitikz package in TikzEdt?

Tags: tikz-pgf, editors, circuitikz

I'm using TikzEdt and I'm currently using the circuits.ee.IEC tikz library.  As far as I'm aware, there is no variable capacitor component.  However, there is a tex package called circuitikz that does but I get a compile error when I try to use it either via \usepackage{} or \usetikzlibrary{}.

Can I use circuitikz and if so, how do I include the package in TikzEdt?

Or

Is there another circuits tikzlibrary I can use in TikzEdt?

Comment: I don't have circuittikz installed at the moment, but if I recall correctly it uses a precompiled preamble. Have you added the usepackage clause in the **preamble part** of the settings and **recompiled** the preamble?

Comment: There is a `standalone` option in `tikzEdt`. Here you can put `usepackage{...}`.

Comment: Does it work, if you add `\usepackage{circuitikz}` under Settings → Compiler? (Well, it works for me.)

Comment: Thanks Ted, Qrrbrbirlbel.  Adding \usepackage{circuitikz} to the preamble/compiler settings worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the line

```
\usepackage{circuitikz}
```

to the preamble (or replace `tikz` with `circuitikz`) under Settings → Settings … → Compiler as in the following screenshot

[image]

Comment: Note:  also need to select [Compilation → (Re-)generate precompiled headers].