# Circuitikz causes error in TikZEdt even with \usepackage{circuitikz} included

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz, compilation-error, technical-drawing, wysiwyg

I'm using circuitikz in TikzEdit, I have put `\usepackage{circuitikz}` in the setting, but in output I saw only node position.
I tried to simplify, but the problem persists.

In Log file I get :

```
! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/R' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.
```

Code :

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) to [R, l_=$Z_1$,*-] (3,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

settings:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,amsmath, amssymb,bm}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage[margin=0cm,nohead]{geometry}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows.meta}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi! I never used TikZEdt, so I can help only a little --- did the `.log` file (wherever it could be) show any error?

Comment: As a wild guess, `tikz` uses `xcolor`, try to remove the loading of `color`... probably not that, but...

Comment: Moreover: 1) you are doing `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}` without loading `pgfplots`; `arrows` is deprecated (use `arrows.meta`); `calc` is loaded by `circuitikz`; `european` is a global setting and not a local one (use `\circuitikzset{european}` just once).  Try to adjust that and comment back. BTW, next time add your code as text also, not only in an image. Thanks!

Comment: I tried to simplify, but the problem persists.
In Log file I get :
! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/R' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

 

\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw (0,0) to [R, l_=$Z_1$,*-] (3,0);

\end{tikzpicture}

settings
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,amsmath, amssymb,bm}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage[margin=0cm,nohead]{geometry}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows.meta}

\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}

Comment: Please next time add the data to the question, no in comments... you can edit your question. It seems that `circuitikz` is not loaded. Try to prepare a small file and check it outside TikZEdt.

Comment: From the full log (in your deleted answer) it seems that the circuitikz is not loaded. It seems that a kind of preloaded latex format is used, you have to regenerate it I suppose. I know nothing of TikZEdt, sorry...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest that to avoid all the paraphernalia of why or what happens with this old program, still useful of course, is to place all the complete code in the main editor and ignore the settings one, since in the main one you can configure everything you require without problems in a single window, on the other hand keep in mind that the environment for these drawings that I know is the standalone, which will deliver a cropped PDF output so that you can import it without problems in your main document.

[image]

You can consult my contributions in the circuitikz tag so that you can see some picturesque contributions, possibilities and perhaps the limits of using this program over time using positioning or relative nodes, you start to imagine the result and return to normal editors as I currently do.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely reason is that you forgot to regenerate the precompiled headers.

Also refer to [tikz pgf - How do I use circuitikz package in TikzEdt? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/130105/250119) to check whether you have correctly edited the preamble.

After it's correct, click [Compilation] → [(Re-)generate precompiled headers] in TikZEdt.